# Drop Down Menu, Keeps disappearing when I hover over it

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Sorry for this,  but  I was trying to edit my code for my website, what i was editing was the drop down menu, when i would hover over the link itself the dropdown menu would appear, but when i hovered my cursor over the dropdown menu, the drop down menu would just disappear, i have asked this question before and thankfully someone fixed, i would really appreciate if someone could help me fix the drop down menu, I also have a problem with moving the "======" header to the very top of the website, for some reason it is unable to go to the very top, but essentially can someone please help me fix the drop down menu, Thank You!

ps. I know that this isnt the correct way to implement my code to this website but im not entirely sure how and im looking to bypass this dropdown menu problem quickly, thanks again!

Source code:
http://pastebin.com/Yuxmi9g9

CSS:
http://pastebin.com/QrpJr68C

Comment: Please use the tools Stack Overflow provides to embed your code into your question instead of linking to it in plain-text.

Comment: Sorry, Im unawar on how do that, is it alright if you could help me out with my question

Answer (score -1):

I wrote your code on https://jsfiddle.net/ssucugx1/

It will be good to show your example more clearly. Your problem can not be solved just with css, or unless you can do that(i.e removes margin between button), it's not a good way.

This problem can be solved easily, if you use javascript, especially jQuery. And I think you are new to web programming(just my guess), using Bootstrap is good answer to you.
[Bootstrap Getting Started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Go to the site, and copy and paste CDN code in your `<head>` and put these code in your project. And your body,

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-default">Dropdown trigger <span class="caret"></span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a href="#">Eat Healthy</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Workout</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Advice</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
</script>
```

That's all. Here is example fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/oh3ck3Lr/

Comment: Thank you, and yea your right, i'm new to programing (14yr)